# flutter @JS annotation meaning

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-engine

I'm trying to add sin and cos functions to the Flutter path. so I have been checking flutter engine codes. i have founded `@JS('window.flutterCanvasKit.Paint')` inside `canvas_api.dart` file. there are lots of `@JS` annotations. I think this is addressing the implementation of the `SkPaint` class right? but how can I find these implementations?

Comment: can you provide a link the exact code?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/main/lib/web_ui/lib/src/engine/canvaskit/canvaskit_api.dart line 871